# Where did my free space go after reducing a partition?

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I have a machine running Centos 6.x, with only one hard drive, 2 TB in size.  I found that it had almost all of that space partitioned to the /home directory, so I decided I wanted to reduce that directory to only 200GB, and use the rest of that space to create a new partition.

I used this guide to do the reduction which worked fine:

http://www.linuxtechi.com/reduce-size-lvm-partition/

The new size of the /home directory is correct, however I can't find that space I freed up so I can partition it (should be well over 1TB free space).

If I run

```
lsblk
```

I get:

```
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                           8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                           8:2    0  1.8T  0 part
 ├─vg_testbox1-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
 ├─vg_testbox1-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0 31.5G  0 lvm
 └─vg_testbox1-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0  200G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

If I go into parted and run

```
print free
```

I get this:

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HUA72302 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   2000GB  2000GB  primary               lvm
        2000GB  2000GB  90.1kB           Free Space
```

Obviously I'm missing something here, just not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your disk usage via LVM, the Logical Volume Manager. Almost the entire disk is given over to LVM. Your "partitions" for `/` and `/home` are allocated out of the LVM space.

You can see the usage with the `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` commands (run these as root). If you want a new logical "partition" for your CentOS system you create one like this:

```
lvcreate --size 50G --name lv_somelabel /dev/vg_testbox1
```

Here, the partition would be 50GB and would be named "lv_somelabel". The volume group "vg_testbox1" already exists on your system. You can then create a filesystem on it, mount it, etc:

```
mkfs -L somelabel -t ext4 /dev/vg_testbox1/lv_somelabel
mkdir -p /mnt/somelabel
mount /dev/vg_testbox1/lv_somelabel /mnt/somelabel
```